# What is my next step using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze, setup.py

Ok so I have python 3.2 installed and I have cx_Freexe 4.2.3 installed.
I have a folder called Python stuff. In this folder there are 2 files. 
setup.py and holg.py (my application)

Here is my setup.py:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None

if sys.platform == "win32":

    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "holgame",

        version = "0.1",

        description = "My GUI application!",

        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},

        executables = [Executable("holg.py", base=base)])
```

The next step I have been doing is Run > cmd:

python setup.py build

what I get is:

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am only a beginner so I need clear steps. Maybe my programs should be in a different folder or something, I can't really be sure. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to put Python on the Windows path, or you need to use an explicit path to python.  Try:

```
$ \Python32\Python setup.py build
```

Here are some good instructions for getting Python installed on your Windows machine: https://openhatch.org/wiki/Boston_Python_Workshop_5/Friday/Windows_set_up_Python

You will first need to `cd` to the directory containing your code and setup.py.  You should find a Windows command prompt tutorial to help with some of this basic stuff.

Comment: \Python32\Python: can't open file 'setup.py' : [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Are you in the correct working directory of your setup.py file ? If not you'll have to have the full path reference for your setup.py

Comment: I moved my setup.py file and my app to the Python32 directory in C:
still the same problem

the beginning of the command line is:

C:\Documents and Settings\User>
if that is any help to you

Comment: I changed the directory to C:/Python32/Python/   .....  then I just typed setup.py build. Everything worked. Thanks for the help